# Accessing CakePHP named vars and PHP GET vars and difference between the two

Tags: php, cakephp

What is the difference between `/action?query=value` and `/action/query:value`

as the latter seems to be the way query strings are handled in CakePHP and how do I do either the latter or the former in Cake?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Example of regular php:**

```
...action.php?name=blah&id=7
```

You can access this like:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

**Example with named parameters in CakePHP:**

```
...action/name:blah/id:7
```

And you can access them like this:

```
$name = $this->params['named']['name'];
$id = $this->params['named']['id'];
```

---

**UPDATE:** It's no longer recommended to use Named Parameters in CakePHP as they have been removed in CakePHP 3.0+

---

**Benefits of using named parameters in CakePHP:**

- Full router support (see @deceze comment below explaining this)
- makes it easier/cleaner when combining with things like Paginate
- better for SEO ([depending on what you're passing](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Named-parameters-VS-GET-td1308231.html))
- you're in CakePHP - use CakePHP stuff <-- he says somewhat jokingly
- ...and more?

**Side note:**

You can also sent parameters via url/CakePHP without using named parameters:

```
...action/blah/7
```

These are retrieved by function vars:

```
function action($name, $id) {
```

Comment: I'd say that the "you're in CakePHP - use CakePHP stuff" is entirely subjective.  Depending on how far you're getting into it it winds up being a lot easier during development to simply submit to the way Cake does things.  I'm an avid supporter of 'we're using the framework for a reason' but at the same time I think it's important to remember that it is Cake**PHP**

Comment: @Charles - That line was meant more as a joke than an actual benefit/reason, hence the "<-- not really..." part.  I agree with you.  You don't want to just follow Cake blindly but - seems a nice way to force consistency if nothing else.  (edited my answer to make joke more obvious) :)

Comment: +1 for **router support**. Named parameters allow you to retroactively change your entire URL schema simply by redefining your routes. You can change `/foo/bar/baz:7` to `/foo/7` whenever it suits you only by editing `routes.php`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you can access the query string parameters the same way you would in vanilla PHP:

```
foreach ($_GET as $param => $value){
    // do stuff
}
```

I've never seen the second method used, but my best guess is that those come through as extra parameters to the controller action and can be indexed by their key similar to `$_GET`. That's a total guess, though.

Comment: The second is a named parameter, which will be available in the $this->namedArgs assoc. array.

Comment: Okay that been said how would I do the following: `$this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => true, 'prefix'=>'admin',
             'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'back' => $this->referer());` so that the back is a query string like `/?back=value`

Comment: You would never do it in Cake like that. You would use $this->request->query or the accessor method.